# Object's field is becoming null after being passed through intent

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-intent

ClassA:

```
public ClassA implements Parcelable {
    private ClassB classb; // Field
    ...

    // Constructor
    public ClassA(ClassB classb) {
        this.classb = classb;
    }

    public ClassB getClassB() { return classb; }
}
```

Class B:

```
public ClassB extends Fragment implements Parcelable {
    ...
    // Just default fragment code, let me know if you need to see it
}
```

MainActivity:

```
ClassB classb = ClassB.newInstance();
ClassA classa = ClassA(classb);
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ItemListActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("classa", classa);
startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

ItemListActivity:

```
Intent intent = getIntent(); // Receiving intent
ClassA classa = (ClassA) intent.getParcelableExtra("classa");
```

BUT, the problem is classa.getClassB() is returning null.
I'm not sure what the issue is, can someone help me out?

Comment: `ClassB extends Fragment` why are you passing an entire fragment ?

Comment: I kind of describe it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64453200/alternatives-to-using-fragments-in-a-master-detail-flow . I'm basically building a settings menu, where for example ClassA could be a specific phone, and ClassB would be "NetworkSettings", and upon selection of ClassB in ItemListActivity (A master/detail flow activity), it would display all the fields like "wifi", "data", that ClassB contains @a_local_nobody

Comment: i don't see a reason why you should pass around a fragment and i'm almost positive what you're trying to do won't work because of that, but i suppose i could be wrong

Comment: Oh in my other post didn't you comment that I would need fragments....? And why wouldn't it work? Do you have any other suggestions for what I could do instead? @a_local_nobody

Comment: `public ClassB extends Fragment implements Parcelable` -- I guarantee you that this will not work in the way that you are expecting. A fragment will have plenty of fields that cannot be put into a `Parcel`. In general, you cannot make subclasses of arbitrary framework classes be `Parcelable`. `Parcelable` is designed for data structures that can be passed between processes.

Comment: @CommonsWare hmm.. well what should I do instead? Is there any way I can initialize and object in Main, pass it to a master/detail flow, and have each field in the object act as/display a separate settings page on the right column upon selection of the field in the left column?

Comment: @CommonsWare Should I just take all the fields inside the fragment (All of them are strings) and just add all the strings to ClassA as fields? I wanted to keep things organized because there's like 8 fragments with ~10 strings each, which means STDevice will have 80 fields... which seems like not good practice? Or maybe I need to create separate classes that model/mimic the fragment class but it doesn't extend fragment so it becomes parcelable?

Comment: With current Android architecture patterns, you should pass around identifiers, not model objects. Activities and fragments have viewmodels, which work with repositories to retrieve model objects based on those identifiers.